# all pairs $(a,b)$ s.t. $a|b^2+b+1$ and $b|a^2+a+1$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$, such that $a|b^2+b+1$ and $b|a^2+a+1$.
>   I just don't know how to start!!!

Comment: You can start by finding which primes can divide a number of the form $k^2 + k + 1$.

Comment: $(a,b)=(1,3)$ is one example...

Comment: This is too similar to a problem that I posted in Brilliant this week. I'd post a solution in a week, if no one else chimes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A look at the pairs $1\le a \le b \le 300$ produced the list
$$1,1,3,13,61,291,1373$$
where the solutions were by taking $a,b$ as adjacent terms in this list. The pattern seems to be that, if you put $p(x)=x^2+x+1$, then
$$a_{n+1}=p(a_n)/a_{n-1}.$$
This pattern projected to the next terms being $6673$ and $31971$, which again produce pairs that work.

The hard part will be to prove all the solutions end up on this list. I'll leave that to you or others. It seems interesting to me that there seems to be only one list, generated as above. Even a proof that if $a,b$ work so do $b,p(b)/a$ would be needed, and might be simpler than showing the list is complete.

Comment: +1 Indeed. You can rigourize everything by using the Vieta root jumping technique, and show that there is only 1 'seed'.

Comment: @CalvinLin In this case, the iteration can be run backwards, so "by reverse induction/descent" one gets back to an earlier case, to show list is complete in another way

Comment: Indeed. The vieta root jumping also allows you to jump backwards, up to the point where $a_i = a_{i-1}$. You then have to check what there can only be 1 starting value (which you found to be $(1, 1)$).